# Popping up a TextBox on mouse click over a PictureBox for adding to grid view

Tags: c#, textbox, popup, picturebox

I try to apply  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549150/popping-up-a-textbox-on-mouse-click-over-a-picturebox-for-adding-custom-note-to-p](http://www.example.com/) to my project in different way.When I click on picturebox, textbox should appear and after it closed on that clicked position that entered value should go to datagridview by row by row with previous data.

But in this method all the time previous data will clear. How should I adjust it

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  // in this case we create a TextBox, but the
  // PopupForm can hold any type of control.
  TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
  Point location = pictureBox1.PointToScreen(e.Location);
  PopupForm form = new PopupForm(textBox, location, () => this.addToGrid(textBox.Text,e.Y)); 
  form.Show();
}


 private void addToGrid(String s,int loc)
 {
     DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow(); this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
     this.dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 1].Cells[0].Value = loc.ToString();
     this.dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 1].Cells[1].Value = s; 
 }
```

Comment: Don't really understand "previouse data"? can you please explain it?

Comment: Its means consider first I click on e.X=10 position and in the text box type 100, then that values are added to gridview by creating a new row. Its haven't any problem. But when I click on e.X=20 and type 200 on textbox and that value is added to next row but previous values (previous row values) are erased. What the reason and How I correct it

Answer (score 0):

I think to resolve your problem you need to do something like this:

```
private void addToGrid(String s,int loc)
 {
     //create a new row
     DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();

     //after initialize  values
     row.Cells[0].Value = loc.ToString();
     row.Cells[1].Value = s; 

     //add row to grid
     this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);       
 }
```