# How to Draw an Editable Text Box on top of a PictureBox in c#

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, drawing

I want to draw a editable TextBox on top of picture box and the user is allowed to enter text into this box.After entering text the text box should  disappear and the text entered should be painted to the picture in the picture box.Please help me on this,I'am doing this in c#.

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("C:\\myImage.jpg");
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
g.DrawString("My\nText", new Font("Tahoma", 20), Brushes.White, new PointF(0, 0));
```

Im stuck with this

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I'm having trouble with drawing the text box on the picture box

Comment: WinForms or WPF?  We really need to know in order to provide an answer.

Comment: I don't know what is a winform or WPF.i want to do this in c# for a windows application.

Comment: Show some code ,don't wait to solve you're problems ,tell us what is not working : TextBox into PictureBox ,Image Drawing ,Graphics etc. because there are lot of details .BE RESPONSIBLE PLEASE!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing "drawing" with the "editable" part.

It sounds like you just want to use a TextBox.  A "basic" demonstration:

```
private Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(256, 256);

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  TextBox txt = new TextBox();
  txt.Location = e.Location;
  txt.Width = 120;
  txt.Leave += new EventHandler(txt_Leave);
  pictureBox1.Controls.Add(txt);
}

void txt_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
  {
    g.DrawString(((TextBox)sender).Text, ((TextBox)sender).Font, Brushes.Black, ((TextBox)sender).Location);
  }
  ((TextBox)sender).Leave -= new EventHandler(txt_Leave);
  pictureBox1.Controls.Remove((TextBox)sender);
  ((TextBox)sender).Dispose();
  pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: @rainbower And the error is?  This was just a basic example of the functionality I think you were trying to achieve based on your post and your comments.

Comment: No.Check the part 'txt.location=e.Location'

Comment: @rainbower What error are you getting?  My code is simply putting a textbox at the location where you are mouse clicking in the picturebox.

Comment: txt.Location cannot be assigned to e.location

Comment: +1 this was really helpful as is this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5549551/495455

Answer (score 1):

Sound like a TextBox control of MSPaint program, is it right?

Try this approach: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/230866-how-insert-text-bitmap-image-using-c

Hope this help.

Comment: Sorry sternr, I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

But in your code the only way to actually draw the text from textBox is to change focus on something else (e.g. by Tab key).

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/7350238/2359840